# ColdFusion 9 ORM: Default value does not work for strings

Tags: mysql, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to create a new string property with a default value:

```
<cfproperty fieldtype="column" name="showIn" ormtype="string" default="credentials" notnull="true" required="false" />
```

After a ORMReload() the column is present in the database, but without a default value.

---

**I expect:**

showIn VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT "credentials"

**I get:**

showIn VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

---

I'm using MySQL 5.1.63 and ColdFusion 9. (Adobe)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dbdefault` instead of `default`:

```
<cfproperty fieldtype="column" name="showIn" ormtype="string" dbdefault="credentials" notnull="true" required="false" />
```

From the [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/coldfusion-orm/define-orm-mapping/map-the-properties.html):

> dbdefault: This sets the default value of a column in the table when schema is exported.